# How do I add the sed command inside a bash script?

Tags: sed

I want to add below line to build.sh file to a line number 26

```
sed -i 's/-DskipTests //' dev/make-distribution.sh
```

I tried with this command

```
sed "26 a sed -i 's/-DskipTests //' dev/make-distribution.sh" build.sh
```

But this is giving error

```
sed: 1: "26 a sed -i 's/-DskipTe ...": command a expects \ followed by text`
```

Comment: How is the error message unclear?  Your `a` is followed by a space, not by a backslash.

Comment: Ought to work. c.f. [the GNU manual](You need to quote your quote since you are compounding quote-types.) What OS and `sed` versions are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it in as if it were multiline add as a workaround. Does this work for you?

```
sed "26 a\\sed -i 's/-DskipTests //' dev/make-distribution.sh" build.sh
```

You need to quote your quote since you are compounding quote-types.

c.f. the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands), though - it ought to work as it is.

Comment: You're welcome! Accept the solution? What OS and `sed` versions are you using? Your original syntax looked ok to me according to the manual...